# Python JSON Update not working as expected

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to update a json file and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. It writes the file just fine but after the file is generated it is not being updated properly.

```
try:
    with open('words_to_learn.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
except FileNotFoundError:
    with open('words_to_learn.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(random_word, f, indent=2)
else:
    data.update(random_word)
    with open('words_to_learn.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

For example this is what I have:

```
{
  "Korean": "word1",
  "English": "word1"
}
```

Each time I run the file I am overwriting the dictionary.

This is what I want:

```
{
  "Korean": "word1",
  "English": "word1"
}
{
  "Korean": "word2",
  "English": "word2"
}
```

Comment: What is the value of random_word?

Comment: {'Korean': 'word1', 'English': 'word1'}

Just a dictionary with two Keys and two Values

Comment: If random_word does not changes among runs, then it will not update anything since its values will be the same that already exist in the file

Comment: Oh. random_word updates to a new random word each time through. So the word in the dictionary is updated but the json file is overwritten with the new word and doesn't keep the old word.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening the json file with 'w' (write) instead of 'a' (append).
If you want the file to update with every writing, try using 'a' to add to the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

At the highest level, you can only have one dictionary in a json file. To accomplish what you are trying to do you need to enclose the dictionary objects in a list.

```
[
   {
     "Korean": "word1",
     "English": "word1"
   },
   {
     "Korean": "word2",
     "English": "word2"
   }
]
```

Now when you write to the file, instead of `data.update(random_word)` do `data.append(random_word)`. `data` is the list from the json file. That way it will append the dictionary to the list of dictionaries .